# Create a nested array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, nested

I'm creating a trivia game which will give the user 4 answer to pick from. Is using an array to include the question and the answer a good option for this game? and if so what is the proper way to create a nested array.

Comment: "Good" and "proper" are both a matter of opinion. I would use an array of objects to hold all of the questions: `questions = [{question: "Which is a fruit?", answer: 2, choices: ["rock", "paper", "pineapple", "scissors"]}, {question: "Which is a colour?", answer: 1, choices: ["ennui", "green", "umami", "cold"]} ]`.

Comment: ohh okay, I was thinking about using that also so I will try that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... in js it's not a problem to make a nested array, but it is a problem if you're thinking of key => value type of array, in that case you need to use an object, you can foreach it's properties as you would with array IF you'd need to. You can store answer values in array (I've been there with exactly the same thing you want to do so trivia  learning game), but you can always use objects and do something like that

```
var userAnswer = 'something',
    item = {
      question: 'what is a?'
      answers: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
      validAnswer: 0;
    }

if(userAnswer === item.answers[validAnswer]) { 
  console.log("is valid");
}
```

some other usage:

```
var userStats = { 
   status: 'alive',
   makeDead: function() {
       this.status = 'dead';   
  },
  bringBackToLife: function() {
       this.status = 'alive';   
  },
}
//then you can even do things like...
userStats.makeDead();
console.log(userStats); //user will be dead
userStats.bringBackToLife(); //user status will be alive
```

I mean you should be fine with array for keeping just question or question and (nested[[]]) array of answers, but then you're starting to play game of array[0] (should be question right?) array[3] (should be invalid answer?) and then what? if you still think your trivia game will never grow then you might stick to that solution, but if you think it might ever evolve just use objects to keep stuff organised.

---

update
Try to keep your objects small & dont make 'god' objects (look up SOLID rules), though if you want to let's say save/have a lesson containing some questions then you could have one big object containing a lot of small ones, i.e.

```
//you can make object to store some data and functions
var LessonItem = function(question){
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = [];

    this.addAnswer = function(answer){
        this.answers.push(answer);
    };
};

//you dont need the 'valid' part if there's always just one valid option
var question1 = new LessonItem('What is?');
question1.addAnswer({text: 'It is something', valid: true });
question1.addAnswer({text: 'It is something  not', valid: false });
question1.addAnswer({text: 'It is something 3', valid: true });

//and this would be our 'big' object, i.e. to save in json file or whatever
var lesson = {
    lesson_subject: 'something',
    lesson_repeat: 3,
    lesson_score: 124,
    lesson_items: [
        question1, 
        //question2
    ]
};
console.log(lesson);
```

but yeah, you can have big 'object' to 'store' others, but avoid creating god-like one huge objects managing everything cause it will become hell with time :D as well im not sure if you're doing that but you can paste in your javascript in google chrome tools console and check if it's working right without reloading page... (for quick checks :))

Comment: Thank you so much, I will use objects then since I like my stuff organized and if I want to modify or re-use the code again in the future, I have this structure to go back to. Also, if I'm planning to have 8 question with 4 choices of answer for each question. Should I have 8 different objects or one big objects for all? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I will, thank you so much. I appreciate your help.